# Drop down list keeps selecting last item from list

Tags: php, html, mysql, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an issue with an assignment I'm working on at the moment. I have a drop down list where I can select a user to send them a message on my website. The problem is that every time I try to select something it will keep selecting the last item from the list instead. The code below is the one I declared at the top of my PHP file upon querying from the database table:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))  { 

  $User_id= $row['User_ID'];
  $USERname = $row['Username'];

  $options.= "<option value=>".$USERname."</option>";

}
```

And this one's where I try to have the list of usernames displayed in the drop down list in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="message_send_new.php">
  <tr>
    <td width="165">To</td>
    <td width="605">
    <select name ="to_username" id="to_username"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?php echo $options; ?>
</OPTION ></select>

</td>
```

I sense something is not right in this line `<OPTION VALUE=0>`but I'm not entirely sure about it.

And after that, I have written these whereby the message sent by a user should be sent correctly to the intended user's inbox and the message should also be displayed in the former user's outbox but for some reason that part is not working right too.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

  $to_username=isset($_POST['to_username']);
  $title=$_POST['title'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $to_userid=isset($_POST['to_userid']);
  $userid=$_POST['User_ID'];
  $from_username=isset($_POST['from_username']);
  $senddate=isset($_POST['senddate']);

}
require_once "includes/connect_i.php";

$query = mysqli_query($myConnection,
"INSERT INTO pm_outbox(userid,username,to_userid,to_username,
title,content,senddate)
VALUES('$Userid','$Username','$User_id','$USERname',
'$title','$message',Now())") or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));

$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, 
"INSERT INTO pm_imbox(userid,username,from_id,from_username,
title,content,recieve_date)
VALUES('$User_id','$USERname','$Userid','$Username',
'$title','$message',Now())")or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
```

I have tried inserting into the tables using the values as seen above before the 2 queries but still I was getting nowhere. I have seen a case regarding the drop down list issue similar to mine somewhere on this website but it didn't help much for mine. I apologize for any careless mistakes in the codes as I have not coded in PHP for quite awhile already. Thanks!

Update:
I'm not sure if this is how it's done. The block of code below is where I'm trying to show that the user is the sender of the message while the last block of code is where I'm trying to show that the message is to be sent to the selected user based on the option chosen from the drop down list.

```
$sqlCommand= "SELECT User_ID, Username FROM users WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['username']. "'";
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $Userid = $row ["User_ID"];
    $Username = $row["Username"];
}
mysqli_free_result ($query);

if(isset($_GET['User_ID'])){
$to_userid=$_GET['User_ID'];

$sqlCommand = "SELECT User_ID,Username FROM users WHERE User_ID='$to_userid'";
$query=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $to_userid=$row['User_ID'];
    $USERname=$row['Username'];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error with the `option`s you are generating.  It should be -

```
<select name ="to_username" id="to_username"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Select One</OPTION >
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

And you are not setting any value to them - `$options.= "<option value=>".$USERname."</option>";`

If you want the `id` to be the value -

```
$options.= "<option value='".$User_id."'>".$USERname."</option>";
```

Comment: I fixed those but still I keep ending up sending messages to the last user on the drop down list when in fact I selected other users.

Comment: Um.. sorry, you mean the output or something?

Comment: From the webpage or the file itself?